# Symfony form choice disable translator

Tags: php, symfony

I having issues with choice fields which are translated while they shouldn't have to be translated.
Since Symfony 2.7 the toolbar notifies you when there are untranslatable values on the current page. Now I'm actually getting confronted with the fact that this happens. Prior to 2.7 this just got logged, but nothing actually happened with it. In the case of Form field 'date' all the digits are attempted to be translated.

What I'm looking for is a way to disable the translator on a choice field, so that the options are not translated. 
It could be as simple as setting the translation_domain = null or translate = false or something like that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Starting from Symfony 2.7, you can use `choice_translation_domain` option (see [Pull Request #13651](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/13651))

Comment: Just so people don't have to follow the link, the solution is to set `choice_translation_domain => false` to disable the translation.

Comment: It's doesn't work for me. When I set choice_translation_domain => false, the the translate domain change from "private" to "messages". But it isn't what I need.